# Why is jsPDF HTML to PDF export slow?

Tags: javascript, performance, pdf, pdf-generation, jspdf

I'm using [jsPDF](https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/jsPDF.html) to generate PDF files from HTML tables, but it takes more than one second to convert a simple table (5x10 cells) containing only text which is way too long for such a "simple" task. Below are the lines of code responsible for the conversion. What am I missing?

```
const doc = new jsPDF();
const htmlContent = liElements[i].firstChild as HTMLElement;
doc.html(htmlContent).then(() => {
  const buffer = doc.output("arraybuffer");
  resolve(buffer);
});
```

Don't have enough reputition to embedd an image, but [here is an image of the profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IBWS.png) while exporting a 6 page pdf, where 4 pages use HTML.

Comment: Why do you think this should be faster than ~1 second?

Comment: Exporting a PDF with 6 pages takes the same ammount of seconds, which is a super long time to wait for the user. As you can see in the profiler image the pages that contain SVG images instead of HTML are not even visible.

Comment: I think it's just the normal overhead of trying to work with PDFs.

Comment: Then I'll probably just parse the tables myself and draw them directly to the PDF, because that is more or less instant. Thanks for your input.